# Error reading FrontendRequest message content error in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Sometime we are getting "Error reading FrontendRequest message content" exceptions in API Management. Backend calls are actually not failing, and their responses are what we expect. This is not very frequent (a handful per day), but I would like to find the reason.

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that there were some problems (details should be in logs) reading request content from client, that is client that has made a call to APIM service. It's normal to have some of those since usually you do not control where calling clients are or what is their connection quality. But if you have this persistently or do control your clients and sure that there are no problems with their connection, might want to file a support request.